# How to update ticker and remove the last SingleTickerProviderStateMixin

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I currently use a `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` for my tabController.

```
///Creates the controller that controls the tab
tabController = TabController(
  initialIndex: 0,
  length: 1,
  vsync: this
);
```

The user can press a button which updates the tabController so that there are now 3 tabs

```
///Creates the controller that controls the tab
tabController = TabController(
  initialIndex: 0,
  length: 3, <- Change here
  vsync: this
);
```

However, the previous ticker from the last tabController is still in use.

> A SingleTickerProviderStateMixin can only be used as a TickerProvider once.

I was wondering whether it is possible to in effect delete the last ticker and update the new one.

Please note I can't use `DefaultTabController(...)` because I require a tabController for other processes

Comment: tried `TickerProviderStateMixin` instead?

Comment: @pskink It would work but I dont want to be providing tones of tickers with new states

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `TickerProviderStateMixin`.

`SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` is only used when you expect to create a single `Ticker` over the entire time that `State` is active. States are usually long lived, so it is not unusual to create multiple `Ticker`s.

If you're worried about the performance of having multiple tickers, make sure you benchmark first to make sure there is an actual issue. Flutter tries to be performant by default, usually using the APIs in the "sensible" way also gives you good performance